# I'm resizing an image while scrolling in my website, but i cant figure how to make an animation for the resizing

Tags: html, css

Here's a link to my website:
http://62.90.141.70/~seesecu1/index.html

In the code, we have this before scrolling:

```
.tz-image-logo-style-4 img {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}

And this after scrolling:
.tz-header-4-eff .tz-image-logo-style-4 img {
    max-width: 170px;
    min-width: 170px;
    margin-left: -85px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

The resize is working, but I want it to be with animation... to make it more nice :)

Thanks alot.

Comment: Try with transitions - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this:

```
.tz-image-logo-style-4 img {
   ...
   transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

Pay attention to cross browser: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Also, if you do so, the menu will do a ugly animation too.

So:

```
.tz-image-logo-style-4 img {
   left: 50%;
   /* margin-left: -125px; */
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   z-index: 999;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   transition: all .3s ease;
   width: 250px;
}

.tz-header-4-eff .tz-image-logo-style-4 img {
   /* max-width: 170px; */
   /* min-width: 170px; */
   /* margin-left: -85px; */
   width: 170px;
}
```

Those Changes keep the image always in the center. You have to set the fix width all over the way so the browser can do the animation properly.